# In Visual Studio Code is there a way to scope settings and keybindings to a language mode?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code

In **VS Code**, I am aware that you can create files containing global user keybindings and settings, and you can have workspace-specific files for keybindings and settings, but is it possible to define settings or keybindings specific to a language mode?

For instance, I want <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> to mean `FSI: Send Line` when I'm in F# mode, but not when I'm in markdown mode or JS mode.

And I want my tabs to be 2 spaces when I'm in Elm mode, but 4 spaces in C# mode.

I know you can define keybindings with a `when` clause like so:

```
{
    "key": "alt+/",
    "command": "fsi.SendLine",
    "when": "resourceLangId == fsharp"
}
```

Is this the only way to achieve something like what I'm after?

It seems like it would make sense to be able to define settings/keybindings for mode X in their own files somewhere. I don't like having language mode behaviour scattered about in big global files like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio Code have stated that at this time (2016-10-19), language mode settings are not supported, but are being considered. (https://twitter.com/code/status/788301380557561857)

There are a couple of issues on the VS Code Github repository requesting variants of this feature.

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/13532

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/1073

Answer (score 11):

To customize VS Code settings and keybindings based on the programming language, you can use [language identifier](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/identifiers), file extension or extension identifier.

For settings you can use [language entry](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_language-specific-editor-settings) (in `settings.json`):

```json
    "[fsharp]": {
        "editor.suggest.insertMode": "replace"
    }
```

For keybindings you can use the following [`when` clause contexts](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_when-clause-contexts) (in `keybindings.json`):

> `editorLangId`    True when the editor's associated language Id matches.

```json
    {
        "key": "ctrl+e",
        "command": "workbench.action.files.saveAs",
        "when": "editorLangId == fsharp"
    }
```

> `resourceLangId`  True when the Explorer or editor title language Id matches.

```json
    {
        "key": "ctrl+e",
        "command": "workbench.action.files.saveAs",
        "when": "resourceLangId == fsharp"
    }
```

> `resourceExtname` True when the Explorer or editor filename extension matches.

```json
    {
        "key": "ctrl+e",
        "command": "workbench.action.files.saveAs",
        "when": "resourceExtname == .fs"
    }
```

> `extension`   True when the extension's ID matches.

```json
    {
        "key": "ctrl+e",
        "command": "workbench.action.files.saveAs",
        "when": "extension == ionide.ionide-fsharp"
    }
```

---

**note:**
I did not test all of these clauses, but `editorLangId` and `resourceExtname` work for me fine.

Comment: Is it possible to add a token or a scope too? e.g. do something else when on a variable name vs html tag. My case - renaming.